# Laravel call a controller within a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal, laravel-5.4

I have 2 controllers, one is responsible for submitting a form to the DB, the other is for PayPal integration such as this one:-

http://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-54

I want it so that when the user presses the submit button, it does its usual DB transactions but then calls the PayPal controller to process the payment.

Is it better merge the 2 controllers into one or to call the PayPal controller as part of the store method??

Comment: IMHO , keep it. Maybe in a near future you would need to add more pay slips

Answer (score 1):

You can call another controller using the following method.

```
$controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\PaypalController');
app()->call([$controller, 'process'], [$request]);
```

Where your controller function is defined as:

```
public function process(Request $request) {}
```

While not the greatest practice, I have used this for calling a function referenced in a console command and in a URL.

Answer (score -1):

In the function which do the DB transactions, try redirecting to your paypal function:

```
public function myDBFunc() {
    /* do transactions */

    return redirect()->route('paypalRoute');
    // or return redirect()->action('PaypalController@paypalFunc');
}
```

Do not forget to pass your variables to your route/action.